# What is the best way to approach reverse recursion to generate XML breadcrumb, using attributes, at each node?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, recursion

I'm currently storing some data in XML files and I need to now generate a file for another application. This application requires that each line includes the path to it. I'm currently developing in C#.

Example XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <root name="Master">
      <Menu name="Menu One">
         <Entry name="Data One">
            <Value>Data goes here</Value>
         </Entry>
         <Menu name="Sub Menu One">
            <Entry name="Sub Data One">
               <Value>Data goes here</Value>
            </Entry>
         </Menu>
      </Menu>
      <Menu name="Menu Two">
         <Entry name="Data Two">
            <Value>Data goes here</Value>
         </Entry>
         <Menu name="Sub Menu Two">
            <Entry name="Sub Data Two">
               <Value>Data goes here</Value>
            </Entry>
            <Menu name="Sub Sub Menu Two">
               <Entry name="Sub Sub Data Two">
                  <Value>Data goes here</Value>
               </Entry>
            </Menu>
         </Menu>
      </Menu>
</root>
```

I would like to build an output that (in the example of "Sub Sub Data Two") looks like:

```
Menu Two --- Sub Menu Two --- Sub Sub Menu Two --- Sub Sub Data Two
```

The XML is generated graphically, so it is possible to have very deep trees of information, so I'm hoping that LINQ or some recursive function can help me here.

Current approach is something like:

```
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(root));
            root resultingMessage = (root)serializer.Deserialize(new XmlTextReader(xFileLocation));

            try
            {
                foreach (var menu in resultingMessage.MenuItem)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        foreach (var val in menu.val)
                        {
                            WriteToFile((menu.name + "..." + ahk.shortcut + " " + val.name + "..."));
                        }

                        foreach (var menu1 in menu.MenuItem1)
                        { 
                            try
                            {
                                foreach (var val in menu1.val)
                                {
                                    WriteToFile((menu.name + "..." + menu1.name + "..." + ahk.shortcut + " " + val.name + "..."));
                                }

                                foreach (var menu2 in menu1.MenuItem1)
                                {
                                    try
                                    {

                                        foreach (var val in menu2.val)
                                        {
                                            WriteToFile((menu.name + "..." + menu1.name + "..." + menu2.name + "..." + val.shortcut + " " + ahk.name + "..."));
                                        }
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception)
                                    {
                                        //ignore
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception)
                            {
                                //ignore
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        //ignore
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //ignore
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes, I'd write a recursive function to do this. Can we see yours?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I'm currently serializing the file, then using nested foreach statements to accomplish this. I'm not familiar enough with XML / or recursion to know where to start or what to search for.

Comment: So many try/catches... Storing the data in a buffer before writing it to a file may not be a bad idea. Try starting by writing a function that recursively calls itself for its child nodes and passing in the path thus far.

Answer (score 0):

Using [LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview) resolves this task, just rely on [DescendantsAndSelf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.descendantsandself?view=netframework-4.8)-method that makes recursive search):

```
var x = XElement.Parse(xml);

var result = x.Elements("Menu")
    .Select(v =>
    {
        var menuElements = v.DescendantsAndSelf("Menu").ToArray();

        var lastEntryElement = menuElements.Last().Element("Entry");

        var menuNames = string.Join(" --- ", menuElements.Select(m => m.Attribute("name")?.Value ?? "?"));

        return lastEntryElement == null
            ? menuNames
            : $"{menuNames} --- {lastEntryElement.Attribute("name")?.Value ?? "?"}";
    })
    .ToArray();

/*
Result of execution:

    [0]: "Menu One --- Sub Menu One --- Sub Data One"
    [1]: "Menu Two --- Sub Menu Two --- Sub Sub Menu Two --- Sub Sub Data Two"
    [2]: "Menu Three (no Menu-children) --- Data One"
    [3]: "Menu Four (empty)"
*/
```

The source data:

```
var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<root name=""Master"">
    <Menu name=""Menu One"">
        <Entry name=""Data One"">
            <Value>Data goes here</Value>
        </Entry>
        <Menu name=""Sub Menu One"">
            <Entry name=""Sub Data One"">
                <Value>Data goes here</Value>
            </Entry>
        </Menu>
    </Menu>
    <Menu name=""Menu Two"">
        <Entry name=""Data Two"">
            <Value>Data goes here</Value>
        </Entry>
        <Menu name=""Sub Menu Two"">
            <Entry name=""Sub Data Two"">
                <Value>Data goes here</Value>
            </Entry>
            <Menu name=""Sub Sub Menu Two"">
                <Entry name=""Sub Sub Data Two"">
                    <Value>Data goes here</Value>
                </Entry>
            </Menu>
        </Menu>
    </Menu>
    <Menu name=""Menu Three (no Menu-children)"">
        <Entry name=""Data One"">
            <Value>Data goes here</Value>
        </Entry>
    </Menu>
    <Menu name=""Menu Four (empty)"">
    </Menu>
</root>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using recursion as I couldn't get LINQ to successfully traverse the entire structure (a lack of knowledge, not a lack of LINQ!)

Code as follows:

```
private string AHKoutput;

foreach (var menu in resultingMessage.MenuItem)
{
  Recurse(menu, menu.name);
}


private void Recurse(MenuItem menuit, string title)
{
    if (menuit.AHKEntry != null && menuit.AHKEntry.Any())
    {
        foreach (var ahk in menuit.AHKEntry)
        {
            AHKoutput = AHKoutput + (title);
        }
    }

    if (menuit.MenuItem1 != null && menuit.MenuItem1.Any())
    {
        foreach (var menuItem in menuit.MenuItem1)
        {
            Recurse(menuItem, title + "..." + menuItem.name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview) is designed specially to work with XML.

Comment: @vladimir I think it could be a case of malformed structure then. I'm investigating at present.